# Appropriate Control to handle dropdown-style functionality with hundreds of values

Tags: ios

I'm trying to port a web form to an iOS view. The Web form has some dropdown controls populated with a few hundred values. In the iOS view, I can use a Picker Control or implement an improvised autocomplete control using a TableView. Neither of them seems like a satisfactory way of doing it.

The pickerview would be tedious to navigate through a few hundred values.

The autocomplete would allow custom user values which is not idea. I want the user to only be able to pick from the provided list of values.

Any other ideas? [An example of the web form that I'm porting:](http://www.thegovernmentpaycheck.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would push a full screen `UITableViewController` which uses the alphabetical selector on the side (see the built in Contacts.app on iOS). This way the user can quickly navigate to the first letter of the option they would like to pick and drill down to their final selection much faster.

You can get even fancier and design a custom view which contains a search field at the very top (again, just like Contacts.app) which will filter the large list of predefined entries as the user types a few characters. This ensures that they only select from the provided list of values but also provides an even faster mechanism.

Here is a screenshot of the full screen `UITableViewController` with search box I'm referring to from the default Contacts.app:

[image: Contacts App screenshot from iOS 7]